# Suggested books on Leibniz notation (differentials)?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, book-recommendation, differential

I'm a freshman in Computer Engineering (but will probably switch to Math very soon) and I've followed some course in Analysis 1 and 2. I found the concept of differentials really interesting, but I've never really grasped the real meaning of the Leibniz notation, such as in:

$$\int {x\ dx} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{dy}{dx}$$

In integrals I think of it as a multiplication between a quantity $x$ and another one $dx$. This machine is building small rectangles that will add up to an area. I've studied the integral definitions and I know that there is definitely more behind it (particularly sums), but this is a useful representation that I have in my mind that allow me to conceptualize problems, especially in phisics.

In derivatives I see $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as a division, between something that I want to calculate ($dy$), that is getting smaller and smaller, and an inifnitesimal distance $dx$. But, especially for derivates, I don't really get how is it possible for the ratio of two infinitesimals to output a real number. I know that this is involved with limits, and limits can do these magical things, but it's just not intuitive for me.

Not considering the last doubt, I think that there is much more about the concept of differential that I do not really know. Thus, considering our beautiful math sections we have in our university library, I'm searching for book suggestions about this awesome topic to learn something more about it!
Thanks.

Comment: Hmm I guess it is mostly just a heuristic. As you go into higher levels in math courses, you stop mentioning it at all (unless you're doing some niche stuff like non standard analysis ig). There is smthn called the "exterior derivative" which "looks the same" but is entirely different conceptually.

Comment: Before studying differentiation and integration, you should study limits.  There are formal definitions of what is meant by suggestive notations such as $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0$$

Comment: Hey welcome to Math SE! In fact in most physics class, definition of integration and derivative, motivated in that way(the way you describe your intuition). If you use this “lousy” intuition, you will get “lousy” result (ratio of two infinite). If you are looking precise definition of integration and derivative, I would recommend you to see Principles of mathematical analysis by Prof. Walter Rudin. This book is also known as Baby Rudin.